# Error inserting file content in SQL Database using mssql php

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database, file

I'm trying to upload files (pdf, images) into the database using PHP and MSSQL.

```
<form role="form" action="kyc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="aadhaar">Aadhaar Card</label>
                    <input type="file" name="aadhaar" id="aadhaar" accept="application/pdf,image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $client_id; ?>" name="clientCode">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn blue">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the PHP code which is executed post form submission:

```
$clientCode = $_POST['clientCode'];
$fileName=$_FILES["aadhaar"]["name"];
$fileType = $_FILES['aadhaar']['type'];

//Get the content of the image and then add slashes to it 
$fileTemp=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['aadhaar']['tmp_name']));

//Insert the image name and image content in image_table
$query="INSERT INTO KYCSCANS (FIRMNUMBER, CLIENTCODE, FILENAME, FILETYPE, FILECONTENT, TIMESTAMP, CREATIONTIMESTAMP, ADDEDBY, FILERELATED) VALUES('Global','{$clientCode}', '{$fileName}', '{$fileType}', '{$fileTemp}', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 'madWeb', 'temp')";

$insertQuery = sqlsrv_query($jarvisconnection, $query);

if(!$insertQuery) {
    die("Aadhaar Query Failed" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Here's the table structure -

```
SRNO - int
FIRMNUMBER - nchar(10)
CLIENTCODE - nvarchar(50)
FILENAME- nvarchar(50)
FILETYPE - nvarchar(50)
FILECONTENT - varbinary(MAX)
TIMESTAMP - datetime
CREATIONTIMESTAMP - datetime
ADDEDBY - nchar(15)
FILERELATED - nvarchar(50)
```

I tried a lot of things but I'm still getting the following error:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 0
>   [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Syntax
>   error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Syntax error, permission
>   violation, or other nonspecific error ) )

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things, but most likely culprit is binary content in the file. Use proper parameterization to ensure the data is sanitized, and to improve security. You should also have some checks on the data to ensure data is not too long for your database columns, and truncate or reject as needed.

```
<?php
$clientCode = $_POST["clientCode"];
$fileName   = $_FILES["aadhaar"]["name"];
$fileType   = $_FILES["aadhaar"]["type"];
$fileTemp   = file_get_contents($_FILES["aadhaar"]["tmp_name"]);
$parameters = array(
    $clientCode,
    $fileName,
    $fileType,
    array($fileTemp, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY)
);
$query      = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO KYCSCANS (
    FIRMNUMBER, CLIENTCODE, FILENAME, FILETYPE, FILECONTENT, 
    TIMESTAMP, CREATIONTIMESTAMP, ADDEDBY, FILERELATED
) 
VALUES (
    'Global', ?, ?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 'madWeb', 'temp'
)
SQL;

$insertQuery = sqlsrv_query($jarvisconnection, $query, $parameters);

if ($insertQuery === false) {
    die("Aadhaar Query Failed" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using your code but now I'm receiving the following error - Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Check my edits, and [read the documentation](http://php.net/sqlsrv_query) on the function.

Comment: When I used the edited code, it gave me the following errors:

Use of undefined constant SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING - assumed 'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING' in...

AND 

Use of undefined constant SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY - assumed 'SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY' in...

Then I changed the parameter array to `code` $parameters = array(
            $clientCode,
            $fileName,
            $fileType,
            array($fileTemp, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_BINARY(1800))
        ); `code`

But then this error0: 

String data, right truncation